# Prove Borel sigma-algebra translation invariant

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone explain: Let $B$ be a Borel set and $B + a = \{ x + a : x \in B\}$. Why is $B + a$ a Borel set?

I think I have to use some good set principle but not sure how to complete the proof.

Comment: This amounts to showing that the family of invariant Borel sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra that contains all Borel sets.

Answer (score 18):

Translation ($T_a(x) = x+a$) is continuous, hence Borel measurable. Hence $B+a = T_{-a}^{-1} B$ is (Borel) measurable.

**Alternative proof**:

Let ${\cal B}$ be the Borel sets, and let ${\cal B'} = \{ A \in {\cal B} | A+ \{x\} \in {\cal B} \}$. Note that ${\cal B'} \subset {\cal B}$ and a little bit of work shows that ${\cal B'}$ is a $\sigma$ field.
Since the open intervals are in ${\cal B'}$ we have ${\cal B} \subset {\cal B'}$ and hence they are equal.

Comment: Can we do without without appealing to measurable functions? It seems that measurable functions is a slightly more advanced definition, and we ought to be able to show this just using definitions of $\sigma$-algebras and less advanced theorems like $\sigma(\mathcal{I}) = \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @Ray I added an alternative proof, but it is only one step away from using continuity/measurability,

Comment: Ah yes! The set $\mathcal{B}'$ was the key! My dumb brain was just focused on $\mathcal{B} + x$. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what $\{ A \in \mathcal{B} | A + {x} \in \mathcal{B} \}$ means. What is $x$? Is it how much we are translating the set (because it's $a$ in the first line)? Is $\mathcal{B}'$ the set of all Borel subsets translated by $x$ that is still a Borel subset?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan  $A+\{x\} = \{a+x | a \in A\}$. The collection ${\cal B'}$ consists of the Borel subsets whose translation by $x$ is also a Borel set.

Answer (score 6):

Let translation be $T_a(B)=a+B$. Then it is easy to show that $T_a(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a $\sigma$-field. It can also be easily shown that $T_a(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ contains the field of finite disjoint unions of right semi-closed intervals (say $\mathcal{F}_0$). and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_0)$.

Therefore, $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset T_a(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})).$$

Now, to prove that $T_a(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$) $\subset$ $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ note that $T_{-a}(T_a(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ $\forall a$.

Suppose that $ \exists \omega \in T_{a}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $\omega$ $\notin \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But we have $T_{-a}(\omega)$ $\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $a$ can be replaced by $-a$, we have our proof.

Comment: Wait, in order to answer OP's question, we don't need the first half of your answer right? We just need to show that $T_{a}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, right? So we only need the last bit of your answer.

Comment: Also, I still don't understand your last sentence, "since $a$ can be replaced by $-a$, we have our proof".

Answer (score 2):

Here, my aim is to show that $B + x = B$. My answer uses a slightly more simple notation than the other answers so hopefully it is some use! It is essentially the proof found here.
http://www.math.fsu.edu/~roberlin/maa5616.f13/translationinv.pdf

Firstly, we denote the collection of sets $M= \{A +x : A \in \Sigma\}$, the proof that this is a sigma-algebra can be found here [Prove that if $A$ is a Borel set, then so is $x + A$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703699/prove-that-if-a-is-a-borel-set-then-so-is-x-a-for-every-x-in-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1). We let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the set of all $\sigma$-algebras.

Then $B_{\mathbb{R}} = \cap_{M \in \mathcal{M}}M$.

Then $B_{\mathbb{R}} = \cap_{M \in \mathcal{M}}(M+ x) = \cap_{M \in (\mathcal{M}+x)} M $. It will suffice to show that $\mathcal{M} + x = \mathcal{M}$. We have that $M \in \mathcal{M} +x$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Thus, $\mathcal{M}+x \subset \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M} = (\mathcal{M} + x) - x \subset \mathcal{M} + x$ and so $\mathcal{M} + x = \mathcal{M}$.

Answer (score -1):

In this question I tried to prove that the set $B+t$ is an open set, so it is a member in the smallest sigma algebra that contains $B$, so $B+t$ will be a Borel set. Here I assume that $B = (a,b)$ and I must study when $t = a$ or $t = b$ and when $a<t<b$. Is this answer enough or not?

Answer (score -2):

Borel measurable functions mean the **preimage** of Borel set is Borel. Therefore we use subtraction instead of addition. 
    Take $B\subset \mathbb R$, and $t\in\mathbb R$, then take $f(b) = b-t$ $\forall b\in B$. This is continuous, thus Borel measurable. Therefore, $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable. However, $f^{-1}(B)$ is exactly $t+B$, therefore, $t+B$ is Borel measurable.