# Prove that if $A$ is a Borel set, then so is $x + A$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, define $x + A = \big\{ x + a \mid a \in A \big\}$.

Prove that if $A$ is a Borel set, then so is $x + A$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Borel set is generated by the open sets on $\mathbb{R}$, so showing that open sets are invariant under translation is suffice.

Exactly how to do this depends on your definition of open set. You can achieve it using the fact that translation $x \mapsto x + a$ is a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$.